# Moving By Reference for strings?

Tags: c++, string

In my class I wrote the following line:

```
string t1,t2;
MyClass(std::string tmp1, std::string tmp2) : t1(from), t2(to) {}
```

To improve performance I could change it to:

```
string t1,t2;
MyClass(const std::string &tmp1, const std::string &tmp2) : t1(from), t2(to) {}
```

But in that case won't the original arguments the the class members share the same string? (Both point at same object)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start from the end:

> But in that case won't the original arguments the the class members share the same string? (Both point at same object)?

Each of your strings is a separate value. Nothing is being shared between them, regardless where you initialize them from. If you initialize a string from a `const&`, a copy of the data is still being made.

> To improve performance I could change it to:

You could, but that would have very slim chance of improving anything at all. You might be skipping one constructor call, but realistically that's gonna be optimized away anyway.

The common, idiomatic way to write such code is to capture by-value, and move out of said value *if you need to store the value for later*; otherwise take by const-ref.

```
MyClass(std::string t1, std::string t2) : t1(std::move(t1)), t2(std::move(t2)) {}
```

Comment: That's the right pattern to use for sink parameters. `++good;`